# Javascript caching tools and techniques

Tags: javascript, jquery, scriptaculous

I have a requirement where in I want to loop through all the DropDown (select) controls on a page. I am picking all the DropDown controls using:

```
var DropDowns = document.getElementByTagName('select');
```

I loop through these DropDowns to set an option programatically of few controls:

```
for (i=0; i<= DropDowns.Length; i++)
{
    var CurrentControl = DropDowns[i];
    CurrentControl.options[CurrentControl.selectedIndex].value = 1;
}
```

Is there any Javascript framework which supports caching? I want to cache all the DropDown control names and loop through the cached names instead of directly looping through Document object.

Are there any tricks to increase the performance of the loop?

Comment: Before you start micro-optimizing, how many drop down controls are we talking about?

Comment: Thirty to forty but can be more also.

Comment: `$.each()` in jQuery.

Comment: Well, I guess a cookie will do it - first time it runs it does the above and also creates (say) a CSV string of select names and writes it to a cookie.  Add in a bit of code to check for cookie, if it exists and is valid then use the names from that.  Whether this would actually be any faster though - who knows ?!  Test it I guess.

Comment: Simply cache the `DropDowns` variable. You don't need to call `document.getElementByTagName` each time unless you create new elements dynamically

Comment: $.each being 'fast' is a tough question. But, it is definitely an improvement upon n number of DOM lookups. You will probably have to be doing upwards of 50-100 lookups to notice a difference in speed. However, the little things add up.

Comment: @RKh `$.each()` [isn't fast at all](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/73), it's just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you're going to see huge improvements in performance for a loop that is only iterating through 30-40 elements, but *some* browsers will get a huge speed boost from looping through an array instead of a `NodeList` or `HTMLCollection` as it is called in some browsers that implement DOM level 1.

So, to answer your question, you can "cache" the objects etc. in an array and it should speed up that loop for future iterations.

Be aware that you need to keep this array up-to-date because it is not "live" like the DOM is.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery, it would look something like this:

```
var $menus = $('select');
$.each($menus, function(index, menu) {
    // Do whatever you want to the menu here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting a different approach -
Save the options in a hidden field with a comma separated values and on page load set the values of control by parsing the , separated values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're already doing this much more efficiently than some of the answers describe. Bear in mind you're not continuously looping through the document, you're looping through your cached `NodeList` of `DropDowns`. If you want to change each one of these elements, then you will inevitably need to loop through them to change them individually.